# R Shiny- Error: operation not allowed without an active reactive context

Tags: r, plot, shiny

I'm very new to R and programming, so please excuse me if this is a simple question.

I'm trying to create a Shiny-App that plots different profit scenarios of a betting model depending on the input values chosen by the user.

The controls are: 1. Bet Type , 2. Prediction Model and 3. Staking Strategy.

Essentially, I want to conditionally add new columns to the original dataframe and eventually use some of the new columns to create the plot.

The UI file:

```
ui<- fluidPage(
  h1("Germany"),

  selectInput(inputId="Type", label= "Bet Type",
              choices = c("Home", "Away")),
  selectInput(inputId="Model", label= "Prediction Model",
              choice=c("LASSO", "Step-Model1", "Step-Model2")),
  selectInput(inputId="StakingStrategy", label= "Staking Strategy",
              choice=c("Fixed Amount","Fractional System",
                       "Fractional Kelly")), 
  plotOutput('budget')
  
)
```

The server file:

```
  
server<- function(input, output){
#load dataset   
datafile1<-read.csv("Bundesligaprep.csv",  
                      header=TRUE,stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

#Load required prediction-model
pred <-reactive({
  if (input$Type == "Home")
  {if (input$Model == "LASSO")
    {readRDS("BundesligaLASSO.rds")}
    else if (input$Model == "Step-Model1")
    {readRDS("BundesligaStep1.rds")}
    else if (input$Model =="Step-Model2")
    {readRDS("BundesligaStep2.rds")}}
  else if (input$Type == "Away")
  {if (input$Model == "LASSO")
  {readRDS("BundesligaLASSO.A.rds")}
    else if (input$Model == "Step-Model1")
    {readRDS("BundesligaStep1A.rds")}
    else if (input$Model =="Step-Model2A")
    {readRDS("BundesligaStep2A.rds")}}
})
#add predicted odds and probabilities in new columns 
df <- reactive({
  df<-
  datafile1()%>%
    modelr::add_predictions(pred,var="MyProbsH", type="response")%>%
    mutate(MyProbsX2=1-MyProbsH)%>%
    mutate(MyOddsH=1/MyProbsH)%>%
    mutate(MyOddsX2=1/MyProbsX2)%>%
    mutate(RealOddsB365H=B365H/(1/(1/B365H+1/B365D+1/B365A)))%>%
    mutate(RealOddsPSH=PSH/(1/(1/PSH+1/PSD+1/PSA)))%>%
    mutate(RealProbsB365H=1/RealOddsB365H)%>%
    mutate(RealProbsPSH=1/RealOddsPSH)

#add new columns for budget and profit based on staking strategy
reactiveValues({
  df$profitH<-as.numeric(0) 
  df$budgetH<-as.numeric(100)

  if (input$StakingStrategy == "FractionalKelly")
  {
  for(i in 2:nrow(df[51]))
  {
    if(df[i, 49]<df[i,51] & df[i,49]<=2 & df[i,36]==1)
    {df[i,55]<-(((((df[i,51]-1)*(1/df[i,49]))-(1-(1/df[i,49])))/(df[i,51]-1))*df[i-1, 56]*df[i, 39]-((((df[i,51]-1)*(1/df[i,49]))-(1-(1/df[i,49])))/(df[i,51]-1))*df[i-1, 56])/8
    df[i,56]<-df[i-1,56]+df[i,55]}
    else if(df[i, 49]<df[i,51] & df[i,]<=2 & df[i,36]==0)
    {df[i,55]<- -(((((df[i,51]-1)*(1/df[i,49]))-(1-(1/df[i,49])))/(df[i,51]-1))*df[i-1, 56])/8
    df[i,56]<-df[i-1,56]+df[i,55]}
    else 
    {
      df[i,56]<-df[i-1,56]
      df[i, 55]<-as.numeric(0)}}
  }
  else if (input$StakingStrategy == "FractionalSystem")
  {
  for(i in 2:nrow(df[51]))
  {
    if(df[i, 49]<df[i,51] & df[i,49]<=2 & df[i,36]==1)
    {df[i,55]<-(0.1*df[i-1,56] *df[i, 39])-(0.1*df[i-1, 56])
    df[i,56]<-df[i-1,56]+df[i,55]}
    else if(df[i, 49]<df[i,51] & df[i,49]<=2 & df[i,36]==0)
    {df[i,55]<- -0.1*df[i-1, 56]
    df[i,56]<-df[i-1,56]+df[i,55]}
    else 
    {
      df[i,56]<-df[i-1,56]
      df[i, 55]<-as.numeric(0)}}
  }
  else if (input$StakingStrategy == "Fixed Amount")
  {
  for(i in 2:nrow(df[51]))
  {
    if(df[i, 49]<df[i,51] & df[i,49]<=2 & df[i,36]==1)
    {df[i,55]<-10*df[i-1,56] *df[i, 39]-10
    df[i,56]<-df[i-1,56]+df[i,55]}
    else if(df[i, 49]<df[i,51] & df[i,]<=2 & df[i,36]==0)
    {df[i,55]<- -10*df[i-1, 56]
    df[i,56]<-df[i-1,56]+df[i,55]}
    else 
    {
      df[i,56]<-df[i-1,56]
      df[i, 55]<-as.numeric(0)}}
  }
  
})

#create plot 
output$budget <- renderPlot({plot(df$Count, df$budget,type="l", col="blue", xlab="Matches played", ylab="Budget"
)})

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I encounter various problems, but currently when I run the app, the error message says: "operation not allowed without an active reactive context".
I'm really struggling to get my head around some basic concepts used in Shiny, so I'd appreciate any hint as to why this error occurs. I hope I could make my request clear.

Comment: If you broke down the code into a small example, at what smallest point does it work, and then once you add a certain functionality, when does it stop? I think it has to do with all your if statements, if you ran these outside of shiny on the same data, does it work exactly how you expect?

Comment: The if statements within the individual for-loops work as expected. Regarding the others(those the different loops are nested in and those that should load the required prediction model),  I don't know how to reproduce them as they depend on the values in the select menu of the app.

Comment: Maybe for your situation you can use `eventReactive` instead of `reactiveValues`